# introduction to swt with out drag and drop designer?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I'm interested in writing a small Java application using SWT. I'm a blind individual though so can't use the tipical drag and drop controls in an IDE approach. Pointers to an introduction of SWT with examples in creating interfaces through code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) may give you a good starting point. The snippets are standalone SWT programs that demonstrate typical capabilities of SWT.

Answer (score 0):

The site [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CatalogSWT-JFace-Eclipse.htm) lists lots of swt and jface examples (amongst others) as well.